# Records of ballads of Jerry Garcia

Tags: rock, similar-artists, live-music, jam-band

I am trying to get into the Grateful Dead for a while now, but their jammy style does not excite me too much (I prefer Jazz for that). Their ballads on the other hand seem exceptional too me. They are usually beautifully arranged and the voice and guitar of Jerry Garcia stands out much more prominently than in their jams.

However I rarely find songs like "Death don't have no mercy" of "Live Dead" on the other records I know, with one exception: "Garcia plays Dylan". So my question is, are there other ballad-style records like "Garcia plays Dylan", with such an outstanding Jerry Garcia?

Answer (score 1):

An unexpected album of theirs, which non-Deadheads like me often like is [Workingman's Dead](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLJNbijG2M7OwJo0WBIVZXulb0kqmWYziW).  The material is more folk/country/Americana.  The [review here](https://www.guitarworld.com/artists/workingman-s-dead-grateful-dead-shifted-uncommercial-jam-band-one-worlds-most-popular-acts) gives an idea of how unexpected it was, and how it also propelled them to recognition and success... Other details [in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workingman%27s_Dead).